# marginpar have changed,is it a bug?

Tags: margins, texlive, koma-script, marginpar

In my latex installation, this MWE always gives the warning: `marginpars have changed`, after multiple runs. But clearly, there is nothing changing. Is it a bug?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[debug]{mparhack}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
X{\marginpar Y}
\end{document}
```

Output log

```
DBG: --- checking marginpar 1
DBG: last on page 1 is 1
DBG: 1 <= 1, exiting loop
DBG: === marginpar 1 is on page 1
[1] (./test_marginpar.aux
DBG: 1 != 0!
DBG: 1 == 1
Package mparhack Warning: Marginpars may have changed.
(mparhack) Rerun to get them right.
```

Comment: I think this is Voluntarily by the package.

Comment: from mparhack manual: `The warning should go away after running L A TEX again
(eventually several times if there’s also a table of contents etc.).`

Comment: Seems to be class-dependent. It works fine e.g. with `artice` or `scrartcl`, but not with `report` or `book` (and their KoMa equivalents).

Comment: Because the first two always have the margin par on the same side of the page.

Comment: @Jpi, well still it should not happen, isn't it?

Comment: try `\pagenumbering{gobble}` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: Why don't you try `marginnote` instead and live happily?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are using `\pagenumbering` which resets the page number and so you have two pages with the number 1. This confuses `mparhack` (and hyperref wouldn't like it too). Give the titlepage some other number style, e.g. Roman:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[debug]{mparhack}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\title{}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
X{\marginpar Y}
\end{document}
```

Side remark: It is normally not a good idea to give in a twosided document the second (even) page an odd page number.